# socket.io ignoring url path seems to cause polling GET 404 error

Tags: node.js, .htaccess, url-rewriting, socket.io, subdirectory

I am trying to run a chat script using `node.js` and `socket.io`. I have followed [the tutorial on the socket.io website](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/) and got it to run on my local Windows node server `http://localhost:3000` just fine.

Now i tranferred the project over to a webserver where it will use `port 54321`. Because the server is running an Apache webserver I needed to use a `.htaccess`file to redirect the requests to the node.js server:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^chat/(.*) http://localhost:54321/$1 [P]
```

So my chat script is available at `http://www.examle.com/chat/`

The website will open just fine in the browser, all the HTML is there. However the socket.io features do not work. The console (browser, client-side) show the following error messages:

```
GET http://www.example.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1439208895332-0 404 File not found
```

I've seen similar questions here on SO that have the same 404 problem. The answers are mostly about the correct order of variable in the server's index.js. I tried those solutions just to be sure, but they didn't help. Because the script does work on my local server (without any subdirectory in the url) I think it might be something different. The curious thing is that the client-side socket.io scripts seems to ignore the subdirectory `/chat/` in the request. If I try to open the URL from the GET request manually with the `/chat/` in it it does give me a reply!

```
http://www.example.com/chat/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1439208895332-0
```

This would work!

But how can I get socket.io to actually use the correct path/url for its requests?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On the client, you can set the path as an option:

```
var socket = io('http://example.com', {path: '/chat/socket.io'});
```

Comment: That (basically) did trick. Had to use `io.connect()` instead of just `io()` though. Thank you very much!